# Words are not clear on my Samsung Galaxy Y phone?

Tags: fonts, samsung-galaxy-y

I recently bought a Samsung Galaxy Y phone and I noticed that text is a little blurry in the phone. I compared it with my Samsung Galaxy Ace phone and the difference is quite clear. The displayed text on the Y is ugly.

I have also attached an image of the phone below.

[image]

Why is text displayed blurry on the screen of my Samsung Galaxy Y phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Samsung Galaxy Y is a low spec phone and most importantly this can be observed with its display.

Some common models in comparison (by resolution, pixel per inch, screen size, price):

- **Galaxy Y**: 240x320, 132 PPI, 3.0in, 110EUR
- **Galaxy Ace**: 320x480, 165 PPI, 3.5in, 190EUR
- **Galaxy Nexus**: 720x1280, 316 PPI, 4.65in, 410EUR

The text is blurry because there are much less pixels per inch to allow it to display text beautifully. You most probably can see individual pixels without a magnifying glass in comparison to "HD" displays like the Galaxy Nexus' and such.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The text is blurry in Samsung Galaxy Phone. If the text is not eligible in any apps you can use zoom option. Or you can buy other costlier smartphones mentioned above.